# Is it possible to port a WPF Prism app to Metro

Tags: wpf, prism, microsoft-metro

We have several WPF PRISM based applications.

Can these be ported or will they need to be rewritted when moving to Metro?

Comment: I suggest you read up on Metro development. It uses XAML, much like WPF, so you will probably find a lot of similarity. However, I'd be amazed if you could get away without having to do some work on your UI layer to make it fit, even if you're not using anything that's in WPF but not in Metro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF has a **lot** more functionality than WinRT XAML, so you'd have to find workarounds for all that when you're porting your application. In fact, based on my experience, even Silverlight has more functionality than WinRT XAML.

In all likelihood, you'll have to rewrite your applications when moving to Metro.

Answer (score 3):

Its been ported now..
http://metroprism.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. While answering questions, try to provide more information than just a link. Once it goes dead, the answer loses its value. It's okay to post a hyperlink as long as you explain what it leads to in a couple of sentences.